# Problems after running unity-reset

Tags: unity, command-line, compiz

After installing compiz-config on Ubuntu 12.04, my whole desktop settings got disturbed. No window control buttons(min, max & close) and no window wobbling as earlier. So i executed the command `unity-reset`. 
Now there is no panel and no launcher either. I have tried to change settings in ccsm, but nothing works. please suggest.

aviral

Comment: How did you reset unity?

Answer (score 1):

Don't play with ccsm. Its very advanced tool.

Execute following,

`gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1` this will reset compiz.

Reset unity `unity --reset`

Now reboot.

If things stays same, open `ccsm` make sure you have checked `Unity plugin` in ccsm.

[image: ccsm unity]